# How to get header view created in Nib to fit section header?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nib

I'm trying to create a header view for my section header for my UITableView by using the 3rd option here

http://hons82.blogspot.it/2014/05/uitableviewheader-done-right.html

I've got it working but my view doesn't fit properly, how can I make it fit? and be dynamic? Do I have to use constraints? but how do I do that if the view is in a separate nib and not in the main storyboard?

Here's a screen shot of the nig

[image]

and the problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have constraints, internal to your view -- that is constraints that fix the position of the search bar and buttons inside your view (which should be a UITableViewHeaderFooterView or a subclass). The view itself will automatically be the width of the table view, and the height should be set by you in tableView:heightForHeaderInSection.

Comment: Should I add a view to the main nib view? and then put everything inside that, and then set constraints on the content of the child view, plus the child view itself? Also do I have to set the height via heightForHeaderInSection, why can I not set it via the options in the nib?

Comment: @Phil, you don't need to add a view to the main view. Just add the search bar and buttons to that main view, and make the constraints to that main view. You do need to set the height in heightForHeaderInSection, that's just the way it works.

Comment: I can't get the height to work, I've posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987022/heightforheaderinsection-not-working