# heightForHeaderInSection not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to get heightForHeaderInSection to set the height for my section header but it doesn't seem to be working. I've put this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 60.0f;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *SectionHeaderViewIdentifier = @"sectionHeaderIndentifier";

    HeaderSection *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];


    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

In my ViewController.m file.

Here's a screenshot of how it's not working in the simulator.

[image]

I should also say I register the nib in the ViewDidLoad of my ViewController.

```
UINib *sectionHeaderNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"headerNib" bundle:nil];

    NSString *SectionHeaderViewIdentifier = @"sectionHeaderIndentifier";

    [self.tableView registerNib:sectionHeaderNib forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];
```

Here's the storyboard layout and connections.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show your implementation for `viewForHeaderInSection`

Comment: Does the heightForHeaderInSection: method have no effect? Is this controller set as the delegate of the table view?

Comment: The view is in the nib, and i've set it's file owner to HeaderSection which is a sub-class of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. I've followed the instructions here http://hons82.blogspot.it/2014/05/uitableviewheader-done-right.html for the 3rd option.

Comment: There's no need to change the File's Owner, but you should change the class of the view in your xib to HeaderSection. I'll repeat my question. Is this controller the delegate of the table view?

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshots which might address the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

viewForHeaderInSection should be something like:

```
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20);

    myLabel.text = [self tableView:self.meetingOverviewTable titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [headerView addSubview:myLabel];
    return headerView;
```

Comment: I'm using a view in a .nib.